# Making webpy framework accessible from outside the local network

Tags: python, webserver

I am using ubuntu  12.04.03. I have some basic experience with webpy and I had it working for my LAN just by following the tutorial. The framework needs to be able to be used from outside the local network. I have difficulty seeing how to make the framework accessible from outside the lan. I tried opening a specific port with

```
# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT" then I check: "# netstat -ln | grep 8081 and I get:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

And use `python web_py_test.py MY_IP:8081` without success.

If I understand it at all, we can have a computer connected on a wifi with a non-static IP and there is a way to launch our webpy framework which can be accessible from the outside world. I am experimenting with the hello script:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name:
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
~
```

I observe that nothing is declared in the script about IPs or ports.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the book from the official site:

> By default, web2py runs its web server on 127.0.0.1:8000 (port 8000 on localhost), but you can run it on any available IP address and port. You can query the IP address of your network interface by opening a command line and typing ipconfig on Windows or ifconfig on OS X and Linux. From now on we assume web2py is running on localhost (127.0.0.1:8000). Use 0.0.0.0:80 to run web2py publicly on any of your network interfaces

Note the **Use 0.0.0.0:80 to run web2py publicly on any of your network interfaces**

Most of these frameworks have the same method for running their development servers locally/publicly.

Back to the answer, if you haven't set any configuration file, you need to run your development server using:

```
python web2py.py --ip 0.0.0.0:80 # or any other port you want...
```

[Reference](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Simple-examples)

Comment: I am actually using webpy and not web2py. Do you strongly recommend web2py? For the webpy issue I read that I should set up NAT port forwarding. The ISP needs to forward to me the port of interest

Comment: For web.py you'll need an extra module (flup) to handle wsgi things. Personally i use Flask with Jinja2 templates,it is a small framework but can cover almost any need using a modular approach and various blueprints (addons).